# Assign click to all buttons and then trigger ajax to change div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have this html

```
    <body>
    <header>
      <img src="" alt="BANNER 200PX" />
    </header>
  <div class="contenedorBody">
    <nav id ="cssmenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Eventos</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Noticias</a></li>
        <li class = "derecha"><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
        <li class = "derecha"><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class = "grilla">

      <div class = "col col-sidebar">
        <div class = "module">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae fringilla eros. Quisque sagittis vulputate lorem vitae gravida. Nulla in dui et urna lacinia posuere ut sed orci. Vivamus non sem ultrices dolor tristique elementum vel vel arcu. Donec vestibulum commodo condimentum. Nam pretium nunc sit amet nunc tristique, a egestas lorem sagittis. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent ex massa, aliquet sit amet ante quis, aliquam ultrices tortor. Praesent velit felis, tincidunt sit amet sollicitudin a, gravida sit amet ligula.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class = "col col-content">
        <div class = "module" id = "36" name = "post">
          <h1>Titulo</h1>
            <div class = "col col-desc">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae fringilla eros. Quisque sagittis vulputate lorem vitae gravida. Nulla in dui et urna lacinia posuere ut sed orci. Vivamus non sem ultrices dolor tristique elementum vel vel arcu. Donec vestibulum commodo condimentum. Nam pretium nunc sit amet nunc tristique, a egestas lorem sagittis. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent ex massa, aliquet sit amet ante quis, aliquam ultrices tortor. Praesent velit felis, tincidunt sit amet sollicitudin a, gravida sit amet ligula.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col col-artwork">
              <img src="artwork.gif" class = "artwork">
            </div>
          <button class = "verFrame" value = "">Ver Frame</button> 
          <div id = "contenedorFrame"></div>
        </div>

        <div class = "module" id="7" name = "post">
          <h1>Titulo</h1>
            <div class = "col col-desc">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae fringilla eros. Quisque sagittis vulputate lorem vitae gravida. Nulla in dui et urna lacinia posuere ut sed orci. Vivamus non sem ultrices dolor tristique elementum vel vel arcu. Donec vestibulum commodo condimentum. Nam pretium nunc sit amet nunc tristique, a egestas lorem sagittis. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent ex massa, aliquet sit amet ante quis, aliquam ultrices tortor. Praesent velit felis, tincidunt sit amet sollicitudin a, gravida sit amet ligula.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class = "col col-artwork">
              <img src="artwork.gif" class = "artwork">
            </div>
           <button class = "verFrame" value = "">Ver Frame</button>
          <div id = "contenedorFrame"></div>
        </div>        

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script src ="jquery-2.2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src ="javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

and I want to make an jquery function to assign all 2 buttons of the sections to trigger a jquery post to get the value of an iframe and the append it to the

```
          <div id = "contenedorFrame"></div>
```

My jQuery so far is this :

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contenedorFrame").hide();
    console.log($(this).parent(".module").children("#contenedorFrame").length);
    $('.verFrame').click(function() {
        $("#contenedorFrame").toggle();
        if ($(this).parent(".module").children("#contenedorFrame").length) {
            $.post("get_frame.php", {
                    id: "7"
                })
                .done(function(respuesta) {
                    console.log("Entre");
                    $(this).parent(".module").find("#contenedorFrame").html(respuesta);
                });
        }
    });

});
```

I just want to do the ajax post once and then toogle that div on and off.

Comment: Why are you using `$(this)` outside the `click` handler? What do you expect it to show?

Comment: I wanted to select another elementos inside the clicked button div class module

Comment: I'm talking about this line: `console.log($(this).parent(".module").children("#contenedorFrame").length);`. What do you think `$(this)` is on that line, since you're not in the click handler?

Comment: Ohh that, neh I was just using to debug something and i forget to delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what solved my problem.

```
    $(".grilla .verFrame").click(function(){
    if($(this).next().text().length <= 0) {
        $(this).next().load("get_frame.php", {id : $(this).attr("value")});
    }
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: Good to see you found it.  I was writing off to the side in my spare time so I didn't see your post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rewriting my answer as javascript modular revealing code which will help you write scalable code.

```
<body>
<header>
  <img src="" alt="BANNER 200PX" />
</header>
<div class="contenedorBody">
<nav id ="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Posts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Eventos</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Noticias</a></li>
    <li class = "derecha"><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
    <li class = "derecha"><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class = "grilla">

  <div class = "col col-sidebar">
    <div class = "module">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae fringilla eros. Quisque sagittis vulputate lorem vitae gravida. Nulla in dui et urna lacinia posuere ut sed orci. Vivamus non sem ultrices dolor tristique elementum vel vel arcu. Donec vestibulum commodo condimentum. Nam pretium nunc sit amet nunc tristique, a egestas lorem sagittis. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent ex massa, aliquet sit amet ante quis, aliquam ultrices tortor. Praesent velit felis, tincidunt sit amet sollicitudin a, gravida sit amet ligula.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class = "col col-content">
    <div class = "module" id = "36" name = "post">
      <h1>Titulo</h1>
        <div class = "col col-desc">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae fringilla eros. Quisque sagittis vulputate lorem vitae gravida. Nulla in dui et urna lacinia posuere ut sed orci. Vivamus non sem ultrices dolor tristique elementum vel vel arcu. Donec vestibulum commodo condimentum. Nam pretium nunc sit amet nunc tristique, a egestas lorem sagittis. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent ex massa, aliquet sit amet ante quis, aliquam ultrices tortor. Praesent velit felis, tincidunt sit amet sollicitudin a, gravida sit amet ligula.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "col col-artwork">
          <img src="artwork.gif" class = "artwork">
        </div>
      <button class = "verFrame" value ="" onClick="module.clickButton(this)">Ver Frame</button> 
      <div id = "contenedorFrame"></div>
    </div>

    <div class = "module" id="7" name = "post">
      <h1>Titulo</h1>
        <div class = "col col-desc">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vitae fringilla eros. Quisque sagittis vulputate lorem vitae gravida. Nulla in dui et urna lacinia posuere ut sed orci. Vivamus non sem ultrices dolor tristique elementum vel vel arcu. Donec vestibulum commodo condimentum. Nam pretium nunc sit amet nunc tristique, a egestas lorem sagittis. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent ex massa, aliquet sit amet ante quis, aliquam ultrices tortor. Praesent velit felis, tincidunt sit amet sollicitudin a, gravida sit amet ligula.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "col col-artwork">
          <img src="artwork.gif" class = "artwork">
        </div>
       <button class = "verFrame" value = "" onClick="module.clickButton(this)">Ver Frame</button>
      <div id = "contenedorFrame"></div>
    </div>        

  </div>

</div>
```

Here's the javascript code

```
var module = (function(){
    function clickButton(that){
        toggleContenedorFrame(that);
        ajaxCallToUpdateDiv(that);
    }
    function ajaxCallToUpdateDiv(that){
        //do some ajax call
        $.post('somepage.php',{data:x},function(response){
            $(that).next().html(response);
        })
    }
    function toggleContenedorFrame(that){
        if($(that).next().text().length >= 0)
            $(that).next().toggle();
    }
    return {
        clickButton: clickButton
    }
})()
```

Comment: let me know if that helps as I didn't check the above code just tried to fix the ajax request problem.

Comment: I will test it when i gwt home. But i think the problem was my jquery elementos selectora

Comment: I think the `.done()` function should be equivalent to the callback argument.

Comment: If you want any modification and help do let me know.

Comment: I think its not working, it pops that module is not defined

Comment: replace your entire javaScript code. I've tried it is working. I can send you the file.

Comment: I works only if i put that code in the html withing <script></script>

Comment: I can give u my email if needed but i dont know why it only works with the script in the html, otherwise module. is not defined

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89568037/test.zip try to get it from here. its working.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed was that you frames were using the same `Id`, they should be using classes.  All element `Ids` must be unique.

It looks like you want to

1. click the button
2. get the id from the parent module
3. post to your server
4. inject contents into `.contenedorFrame`

Something like this may work.  But, I think you're main problem was not using a `class` selector.

```
$('.contenedorBody').on('click', '.verFrame', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      $module = $this.parents('.module:first'),
      moduleId = $module.attr('id'),
      $frame = $module.find('.contenedorFrame');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'get_frame.php',
    data: {
      id: moduleId
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success');
      $('.contenedorFrame').hide();
      $frame.show().html(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('error');
    }
  });
});
```